# Sending a syn packet in response to a syn-ack

Tags: networking, tcp, packet

If, for example you connect to google and send a SYN packet from a port to port 80 and google responds with a SYN-ACK. What would happen if you sent a SYN packet to google to port 80 again? Would it reset the previous syn connection or would there now be two TCP connections with google waiting for an ACK response?

Comment: so there would be two pending connections waiting for ACK on port 80 from the google connections?

Comment: If you send it from the same port wth the same sequence number, it will be seen as a duplicate and ignored. If you send it from a different port, it will be seen as a new connection request. If you send it from the same port wiht a different sequence number, it will probably be perceived as an error and either be ignored or cause a connection reset, not sure which.